# What is the rate of change of the diagonal, volume, and surface of a box with dimensions a, b, and c?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am working through some problems in my calculus workbook, and this one has me a bit stuck.
If someone wouldnt mind lending a hand, I would much appreciate it.

This is the problem:

> A rectangular box has dimensions a, b, and c which are changing with time. At $t = t_0$:
>
> $a = 1 m$, $b = 2 m$, and $c = 3 m$ (m is meters).
>
> $da/dt = db/dt = 1 m/sec$ and $dc/dt = -3 m/sec$
>   What is the rate of change of the volume, surface area, and the diagonals of the box at $t = t_0$.

If someone wouldnt mind lending me a hand as to the way you would solve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks
Corey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the volume, surface area and diagonals are given by
$$ V = abc, \quad S = 2ab+2bc+2ca, \quad D = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}. $$
I'll do the volume, and then it should be clear what to do for the others. Differentiate it as a product:
$$ \frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{da}{dt}bc + a\frac{db}{dt}c + ab\frac{dc}{dt}. $$
Now just insert the values you have.

Comment: $S$ works in the same way as $V$: differentiate each product individually (e.g. $d(ab)/dt = da/dt b + a db/dt$), and then add them together. $D$ is a bit more annoying, but if you define $m=a^2+b^2+c^2$, the chain rule lets you write it as $dD/dt = dD/dm  \times dm/dt$, which you can then calculate as before.

Comment: Hey, Thanks heaps for that. Its much appreciated. I think I have it correct, but if you could confirm I would be really grateful: $V = 3 m^3/s$, $S = 4 m^2 / s$, and $D = -6/14 m/s$. Thanks again, Corey :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice, the dimensions of the box $a$, $b$ & $c$ are changing w.r.t. time $t$ hence, we have

1. Volume, $$V=abc$$$$\implies \frac{d V}{dt}=bc\frac{da}{dt}+ac\frac{d b}{dt}+ab\frac{dc}{dt}$$
   substitute all the  corresponding values, the rate of change of volume is 
   $$\color{red}{\frac{dV}{dt}}=(2\cdot 3)(1)+(1\cdot 3)(1)+(1\cdot 2)(-3)=\color{red}{3\ m^3/s}$$
2. Surface area, $$S=2(ab+bc+ac)$$$$\implies \frac{d S}{dt}=2\left(b\frac{da}{dt}+c\frac{d b}{dt}+a\frac{dc}{dt}\right)$$
   substitute all the  corresponding values, the rate of change of surface is 
   $$\color{red}{\frac{dS}{dt}}=2(2\cdot 1+3\cdot 1+1\cdot (-3))=\color{red}{6\ m^2/s}$$
3. Diagonal, $$D=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\implies D^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$$
   $$\implies 2D\frac{d D}{dt}=\left(2a\frac{da}{dt}+2b\frac{d b}{dt}+2c\frac{dc}{dt}\right)$$
   $$\implies \frac{d D}{dt}=\frac{1}{D}\left(a\frac{da}{dt}+b\frac{d b}{dt}+c\frac{dc}{dt}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\left(a\frac{da}{dt}+b\frac{d b}{dt}+c\frac{dc}{dt}\right)$$

substitute all the  corresponding values, the rate of change of diagonal is 
$$\color{red}{\frac{dD}{dt}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}}\left(1\cdot 1+2\cdot 1+3\cdot (-3)\right)=\color{red}{\frac{-6}{\sqrt {14}}\ m/s}$$